# Iframe inside button in html

Tags: html, iframe

How to implement iframe inside a button in HTML? I would like to have normal button, and when I click on button iframe should open? I would like to know only HTML part of the solution. Thank You

Comment: Could you post what you have so far/ some idea of how you'd like it to look?  Would need a little more detail to answer.

Comment: I just dont know syntax for it, I cant have nothing so far :) I was thinking its <button><iframe></iframe></button> but its not, I cant see button at all.i want to have normal button, and to open iframe on click?

Comment: there is no pure html solution for that

Comment: OK, so I don't see a need to nest it within the button.  You could have it wherever you like and use Jquery to 'toggle' the visibility of it.  In any case you will need some kind of JS to show/hide the iframe.

Comment: I will do getElementById in function, but in html part how should be implemented? or there is no solution for that?

Comment: I need this to look like button and to open iframe on click

Comment: Please update your question with what you already have, it helps us better to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a button in javascript that will open iframe when user clicks on that button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022089/how-to-create-a-button-in-javascript-that-will-open-iframe-when-user-clicks-on-t)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions for this type of problem elsewhere on Stackoverflow.  Try searching, but as a starting point something using Jquery like this would do it.  https://jsfiddle.net/s1z18x90/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#iFrame" ).toggle();
    });

});
```